# How to store the value of attribute ID to a variable? Jquery Javascript

Tags: jquery, attributes, javascript

Ok, so this is probably obvious.

I need to get the ID of a clicked div:

```
$("div.editable").click(function(e) {  
  var editid = $(this).attr("id");  
});
```

And the use that ID in a function w/parameters:

```
ajaxStyle(value, 2, editid)
```

But it doesn't work when I write it like this. It either returns "undefined" or just doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var editid;
$("div.editable").click(function(e) {
   editid = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

It's all about function scope.

Comment: wont let me accept yours as correct yet. Will do when I can :)

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring your `editid` variable within a function, so it is only visible within it and not defined outside of it.

This will work (though will pollute the global namespace):

```
var editid;
$("div.editable").click(function(e) {  
  editid = $(this).attr("id");  
});
```